# org.hibernate.loader.MultipleBagFetchException: cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags using FetchType

Tags: java, hibernate

while using fetch = FetchType.EAGER for more than one field I get this exception
To fetch from multiple table in hibernate what else should I use,
My Code is down below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTlnn.png)

Comment: Copy your code in the question, do not use images of it..

Comment: I solved this issue by using @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the exception if you switch from List<> to Set<>.

```
@OneToMany(...)
Set<...> ....
```